# spring + hibernate + gradle -> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gradle

I have a development PC that contains the code of a web application running in apache-tomcat. This code, uses spring and hibernate and in order to generate a .war out I need to use 'gradle'.

All is fine when I generate this .war in this development PC but when I copy all the code to my local PC and generate this war it results in an exception when I start the apache:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workflowController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.test2.section.mastertables.listboxes.service.ListboxService com.test.test2.section.workflow.controller.AbstractController.listboxService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'listboxService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.test2.section.mastertables.listboxes.service.ListboxCodeService com.test.test2.section.mastertables.listboxes.service.ListboxService.listboxCodeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'listboxCodeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: protected void com.test.test2.section.mastertables.listboxes.service.ListboxCodeService.setEntityDao(com.test.test2.section.generic.dao.GenericEntityDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.test2.section.generic.dao.GenericEntityDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 37: commonDao,reinsuranceDao,serviceDao,masterServiceDao,poolDao,lookupCodeDao,lookupLangDao,listboxItemDao,listboxCodeDao,userDao,roleDao,contractDao,subContractDao,premiumsDao,selfRetentionDao,serviceContractDao,salarySumDao,logBookDao,productDao,technicalDataDao,reglementDao,cancellationDao,customerDao,mutableDao,messageSourceDao,populationDao,auditDao,reInsuranceSolutionDao,premiumSplitODao,pensionFundDao,documentDao,tariffBasicsDao,mySamEmployeeDao,mySamServiceDao,mySamContractDao,mySamPensionFundDao,mySamRevInfoDao
>   ...

I have decompressed the two jars generated, one in the dev PC and one in my local PC, and the only differences are in the .class files, the rest is the same: jars, .jsp... I am using in both PC the same gradle version and the same build files for gradle, the same source code, the same java version. I would appreciate any idea you can give me regarding this problem.

**EDIT:**

So I could decompile the classes in the two wars to compare. As suspected this is the result:

Class from working jar:

```
@Service
public class ListboxCodeService extends GenericService
{

public ListboxCodeService()
{
}

@Autowired
protected void setEntityDao(ListboxCodeDao entityDao)
{
    this.entityDao = entityDao;
}

public ListboxCode getByCode(String code)
{
    return ((ListboxCodeDao)entityDao).getByCode(code);
}

protected volatile void setEntityDao(GenericEntityDao x0)
{
    setEntityDao((ListboxCodeDao)x0);
}
```

}

Class from not working war:

```
@Service
public class ListboxCodeService extends GenericService
{

public ListboxCodeService()
{
}

@Autowired
protected void setEntityDao(ListboxCodeDao entityDao)
{
    this.entityDao = entityDao;
}

public ListboxCode getByCode(String code)
{
    return ((ListboxCodeDao)entityDao).getByCode(code);
}

@Autowired
protected volatile void setEntityDao(GenericEntityDao genericentitydao)
{
    setEntityDao((ListboxCodeDao)genericentitydao);
}
```

}

The difference is the extra @Autowired in the non working code. However the initial java code is:

```
@Service
public class ListboxCodeService extends GenericService<ListboxCode, ListboxCodeDao> {

@Autowired
@Override
protected void setEntityDao(ListboxCodeDao entityDao) {
    this.entityDao = entityDao;
}

/**
 * Gets the by code.
 *
 * @param code the code
 * @return the by code
 */
public ListboxCode getByCode(String code) {
    return entityDao.getByCode(code);
}
```

}

So my questions now is, who is the culprit for adding this extra @Autowire? As I said before, it is the same code, the same gradle version and the same java version... any idea? We are planning to use this DEV environment for other purposes and I must ensure before that I can generate working versions in my local PC.

Comment: It looks that the main problem is to create ListboxCodeSrvice because setEntityDao. There are many implementation or childs GenericEntityDao. And differencies in class can be crucial problem. Try share problemation classes: ListboxService, ListboxCodeService, GenericEntityDao, etc.

Comment: @Cyva All the 'commonDao,reinsuranceDao...' extend GenericEntityDao. I think that is what the exception tells. The question here is why when I generate a war in the dev environment it works, however it doesn't not when the war is generated in my local machine.

Comment: You are writting above that in jar files is only one difference: classes. It can be crucial. However with these informations I can not help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could fix it.

I can generate my war file and it runs fine with no exception. I said before that I had the same java version, but it was not really true. In the DEV system (where I could generate right wars), it is 1.7.0_79_b2 and in my local PC I had 1.7.0_80-b15. And that was it... I installed 1.7.0_79_b2 and my war is generated with .class that contains no extra @Autowire. I am still in shock.

Comment: I don't know why this happens. I checked the differences between _79 and _80 and I don't see any sensible change that could triggered this but I tested many times and the result is always the same. _80 adds an extra @Autowire and _79 doesn't.